The iOS keyboard pops up in the middle and then to the bottom
Sometimes when I go from one page to another, the keyboard pops up from the middle, and then when the page is fully displayed, the keyboard falls down again, and this situation doesn't happen every time.
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   [self.phoneNumTF becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
   [super becomeFirstResponder];
   return [self.phoneNumTF becomeFirstResponder];
}

I tried to delay the response time, but it didn't seem to work. Also, deleting keyboard notifications didn't have much effect, and removing the following method didn't work either:
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
   [super becomeFirstResponder];
    return [self.phoneNumTF becomeFirstResponder];
}

